# Display list inline on certain devices with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering if there is a way to make a list display inline on phones, but just horizontally on tablets and desktops. I'm fairly new to bootstrap and have been reading documentation all morning, but can't find anything about this.

Normally I would do this with jQuery `if (window.innerWidth < 768) { $('#list').addClass('list-inline'); }`, but that doesn't work if you `load()` the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS media query to do this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    #myList li {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

This is preferred over using jQuery because it will work for dynamically appended element with no extra code, and it also maintains a better separation of concerns (ie. only CSS should be used for amending the UI)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So it's better to change all those `.addClass` lines to media queries?

Comment: @user3601250 indeed it would be.